# PrimeFaces LazyDataModel the entire page is blocked after rendering dataTable

Tags: ajax, primefaces, lazy-loading

The `load()` method of the `LazyDataModel` is called, and exits with success. 
The `dataTable` is rendered, but the only problem is that the whole page is blocked, the buttons doesn't give any response, except one which is executes JavaScript.

I think there is something with Ajax, while the AjaxStatus shows that something is loading, but there is nothing to load.

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.4.2 with Mojarra 2.1.6

here is my .xhtml, in the options.xhtml is one more h:form declared

```
<ui:include src="options.xhtml" />
      <h:form id="display">
         ...
         <p:dataTable id="resultsTable" value="#{index.lazyModel}"
            var="searchResult" rows="10" paginator="true" emptyMessage=""
            paginatorPosition="bottom" lazy="true"
            rendered="#{empty index.lazyModel ? false : true}">
            <p:column>
               <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                  <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                     <h:outputLink value="#{searchResult.url}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{searchResult.title}" />
                     </h:outputLink>
                     <h:outputText value="#{searchResult.category}" />
                  </h:panelGrid>
                  <h:outputText value="#{searchResult.kwic}" />
               </h:panelGrid>
            </p:column>
         </p:dataTable>
         <p:graphicImage value="/resources/welcome.gif"
            rendered="#{empty index.lazyModel}" styleClass="welcome" />
      </h:form>
```

the LazyDataModel's load Method:

```
@Override
   public List<Result> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
         SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {

      // rowCount
      int dataSize = searchResults.size();
      this.setRowCount(dataSize);

      List<Result> temp = null;
      // paginate
      if (dataSize > pageSize) {
         try {
            temp = searchResults.subList(first, first + pageSize);
         } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            temp = searchResults.subList(first, first
                  + (dataSize % pageSize));
         }
      } else {
         temp = searchResults;
      }

      return searchHandler.classify(temp);
   }
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can't it help if you change the h:form with a form from PrimeFaces? just an ideea ...

Comment: which form do you mean? because as I know there is no PrimeFaces specific form.

Comment: well, I used to work with RichFaces and with Ajax, and there was a a4j:form, that always helped us when working with components from RichFaces and/or Ajax ... so I guess I didn't express correctly with the form from PrimeFaces .. sorry :) ... but anyway, it's just a longshot